# Can I use an if statement inside a try-catch method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using the `guild.fetchVanityData()` method to get a guild's vanity data in my Discord bot using the Discord.js library.
My `invite.js` command throws an error saying `This guild does not have the VANITY_URL feature enabled.`
I know that the guild does not have it enabled, and am sending a custom message to the user telling them that. Hence, I do not want it to throw an error. I'm using an `if` check in my `message.js` event file to swallow the error if the command executed is the invite command (The command throwing the error), using a `return` method. This does not seem to work as it still throws an error.

The only file in my entire bot in which I am using a `try-catch` is at the end of `message.js`.

My code is below, please help me out.

**Message.js event file**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    execute(message, client) {
          const prefixes = ['!1','833376214609690674', "<@!833376214609690674>","<@833376214609690674>"]
      const prefix = prefixes.find(p => message.content.startsWith(p));
      if (!prefix || message.author.bot) return;

      const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
      const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      if (message.content === "<@833376214609690674>" || message.content === "<@!833376214609690674>" || message.content === "833376214609690674" || message.content === "!1") {
      const mCommand = client.commands.get('help')
      mCommand.execute(message, args)
                     }

      if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid command.")

      const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

      try {
        command.execute(message, args, client);
     }
    catch (error) {
      if(command.name === "invite") {
       return
      }

     else {
     console.log(error)
     }

    }

    },
};
```

**Invite.js command file**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'invite',
    category: "utility",
    description: 'Get the bot invite or server invite info.',
    execute: async (message, args) => {
      if (args[0] === 'bot') {

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Bot Invite')
        .setDescription("Returns the bot's invite link.")
        .addFields({
          name: 'Invite',
          value: "[Click here](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=833376214609690674&permissions=4294442710&scope=bot%20applications.commands) to invite the bot to your server."
        })

        message.channel.send(embed)
      }
      else if (args[0] === 'server') {
      
          message.guild.fetchVanityData()
          if (!message.guild.vanityURLCode) {

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Server Invite')
            .setDescription("Returns the server's Vanity URL if it has one.")
            .addFields({
              name: 'Vanity URL',
              value: 'This server does not have a Vanity URL.',
              inline: true
            },
            {
              name: 'Uses',
              value: 'Not Applicable',
              inline: true
            })
            .setTimestamp()

            return message.channel.send(embed)
          }

          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Server Invite')
          .setDescription("Returns the server's Vanity URL if it has one.")
          .addFields({
            name: 'Vanity URL',
            value: `https://discord.gg/${message.guild.vanityURLCode}`,
            inline: true
          },
          {
            name: 'Uses',
            value: `${message.guild.vanityURLUses}`,
            inline: true
          })

         message.channel.send(embed)
        
        
       
    }
}
}
```

I think this is all the code that is required, but if you wish to see my other commands, files, etc., you can go to this repl: https://replit.com/@smsvra6/MultiBot

Comment: yes, you can use if/else inside try and catch

Comment: Your code seems syntactically correct. I would check that `command` actually has a `name` property, and that its value is a string, and that the string's value is `"invite"`. One of those assumptions appears to be false, if you're not entering the `if` block

Comment: @apsillers If you look at the `invite.js` file, it does.

Comment: In that case, are you sure the execution ever enters the `catch` block at all? Possibly the error message you see is logged/thrown asynchronously, or isn't a thrown error? I'd say add more logging to check if you ever enter the `catch`.

Comment: I have an asynchronous function. Do you mean that that is the issue? @apsillers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchVanityData), `<Guild>.fetchVanityData` returns a Promise. Therefore, you can use `<Promise>.then` and `<Promise>.catch` syntax.
i.e.:

```js
message.guild.fetchVanityData()
.then(data => {
    // success, the server has a vanity url ;
})
.catch(error => {
   // error, the server does not have a vanity url.
});
```

There is no need for an if statement.